# Getting INFO in PHP

Tags: php

So, I made a thing where it gets the connection of a game server when you put it in a search box and press submit. Now, what I want it to do is to get the information when I type something like http://link.com/search.php?serverName=hello.com

and that hello.com would be the thing that it gets the information for.

Comment: I see no reason whatsoever for posting the link to your website and not posting any code instead. I think that what you're asking could be solved with a simple Google search like "PHP GET POST variables". This way, one might think instead that you're trying to advertise your site.

Comment: @Numbers i removed my site, i just wanted to test out how it works, like I put in like ?server=link.com and it would output out online or offline

Comment: Got it. I think that there is nothing wrong with showing it, but it is preferable to show the code that you already have instead of linking a website. A screenshot or even a link might be acceptable, but with code it's much better.
Anyway, I advise you look up "PHP GET variables" on Google, what you're trying to do is simply to read the GET variable named `serverName`.

Comment: Too late, I wanted to reply but the question has been closed. Anyway, here is the code you actually need: `$serverNameVariable = $_GET['serverName']`. Then pass the value to whatever processing you are already doing on your website. When a visitor calls `yourwebsite?serverName=test`, the variable `$serverNameVariable` will contain the value "test".

Answer (score 1):

You should consider looking into something called GET which can be added to your HTML form, which essentially adds the content entered into the 'searchbox' onto the URL at the top.

You can try it out using something like this..

```
<form action="search.php" method="GET">
<!-- Your form components here -->
<input type="submit" value="serverName">
```

See above that the value of the submit button needs to be set to what you want to appear at the end of the URL, in this case it would display '?serverName'

Then in regards to processing this data, you will need to look up searching algorithms in PHP, the best method is a FULL-TEXT search, but can be quite complicated to do, there are others that will get the job done.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Some more useful links:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm